# homotopy theory for simplicial profinite topological spaces, and the décalage shift endofunctor

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Is there a homotopy theory for simplicial profinite sets where the notion of contractibility can be defined in terms of the decalage endomorphism ?

Specifically, I need a homotopy theory where notion of contractibility is described by the following diagram:

> A profinite set $X_\bullet$ is *contractible* iff
> $ \operatorname{const}X_0\times X_\bullet \xrightarrow {\operatorname{id}} \operatorname{const}X_0\times X_\bullet$ factors as $$\operatorname{const}X_0\times X_\bullet \longrightarrow X_\bullet\circ[+1] \xrightarrow {\operatorname{pr'} \times \operatorname{pr''}}  \operatorname{const}X_0\times X_\bullet
> $$
> Here $[+1]:\Delta\to\Delta$ is the decalage morphism $n\mapsto n+1$ adding a new minimal element to each finite liner order, and $\operatorname{pr'}: X_\bullet\circ[+1]\to  \operatorname{const}X_0$, $,  \operatorname{pr''}: X_\bullet\circ[+1]\to  X_\bullet$ are the standard maps corresponding to taking the 0-th face, and all the non-0 faces.

Does this hold for the homotopy theory of simplicial profinite sets mentioned in a comment by Peter Heine:

> There is a good homotopy theory of simplicial profinite sets. See Quick's paper [Profinite homotopy theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.4082.pdf). For a slightly different perspective, see [§E.1.6](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/SAG-rootfile.pdf#subsection.E.1.5) of Spectral algebraic geometry. Two other useful resources are §7.4 of [Pro-categories in homotopy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.01564.pdf) theory by Barnea–Harpaz–Horel and [Simplicial model structures on pro-categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.07539.pdf) by Blom–Moerdijk. –
> Peter Haine

Is there any source explicitly discussing the decalage shift $[+1]:\Delta\to\Delta$ action on the category of simplicial profinite sets ?

Note that in simplicial sets this property does define contractibility; in fact a ``nice'' topological space is contractible iff there is a factorisation as above for its singular complex.

Ideally, I would like a homotopy theory which ``thinks'' of the factorisations through the decalage as homotopies $Cone(X)\to X$ or $\Sigma X \to X$ from the cone or suspension of $X$. Note, however, that this diagram only allows one to talk about contracting homotopies, not homotopies between two maps $f:X\to X$ in general.

A weaker requirement is the following. A connected profinite set $X_\bullet$ is contractible iff $X_\bullet\xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}} X_\bullet$ factors as
$$ X_\bullet \longrightarrow X_\bullet\circ[+1] \xrightarrow {\operatorname{pr'} \times \operatorname{pr''}}   X_\bullet
$$
However, here it is not quite clear what ``connected'' profinite set should mean.

Motivation. A possible example of such a simplicial profinite set is the classifying space $B(G)$ for a profinite group $G$.

Comment: There is a good homotopy theory of simplicial profinite sets. See Quick's paper [*Profinite homotopy theory*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.4082). For a slightly different perspective, see [§E.1.6](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/SAG-rootfile.pdf#subsection.E.1.5) of *Spectral algebraic geometry*. Two other useful resources are §7.4 of [*Pro-categories in homotopy theory*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01564) by Barnea–Harpaz–Horel and [*Simplicial model structures on pro-categories*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.07539) by Blom–Moerdijk.

Comment: Neither of these sources uses the word 'decalage'(décalage). Do you know of any source which discusses the décalage edomorphism $[+1]:\Delta\to\Delta$ in the context of simplicial profinite sets ? In particular, whether my diagrams above define a notion related to their homotopy theory.

Comment: I will look carefully at these sources, of course, and thought I should ask explicitly first.

Comment: In fact, let me now  update the question, using your references. Thank you!